# Is the 'n' in Delta G = -nFE, ever negative?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry, energy

Is it possible for $n$ in $\Delta G=-nFE$ to ever be negative? Trying to figure out where I went wrong on some thing and want to rule that out.

Answer (score 8):

No. This result occurs from the [Nernst equation](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Thermodynamics/State_Functions/Free_Energy/Gibbs_Free_Energy/Gibbs_Free_Energy).

The "n" is the number of electrons transferred. If no electrochemical reaction occurred, then n = 0.

Otherwise "n" is positive.

Having a negative number of electrons transferred would be impossible.

Comment: If no electrochemical reaction occurred, then n = 0. really?

Comment: The lowest limit is when no oxidation or reduction occurs. At that point, n = 0. I answered the OP's question, which is that it can never be negative.

Comment: And indeed, there is a direct relationship between Nernst and $\Delta G = -n F E$ as indicated in the link in my answer (i.e., [here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Thermodynamics/State_Functions/Free_Energy/Gibbs_Free_Energy/Gibbs_Free_Energy#Relating_Free_energy_to_Cell_potentials)) or in many other sources.

Comment: @ADG I think you're being incredibly rude. I teach physical chemistry. I don't need to look this up on Google.

Comment: Could it be that both these standard equations can be derived from each other? Backtracing the chemwiki derivation?

Comment: Indeed, derivations can go both directions.

Comment: @ADG I've been responding to flags for 5 minutes and I've run into a multitude of rude, obnoxious, and otherwise non-constructive comments that you've left.  It's going to be a matter of shape up or ship out here.  Some radical changes need to be made **immediately**.  Every user here deserves your utmost respect and courtesy and no one needs your grandstanding.

Comment: @ADG, it's not wrong, because you can derive the Nernst equation without using that exact formula ([here's one example, using the Boltzmann distribution.](http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/elmat_en/kap_2/backbone/r2_4_3.html)).

Comment: @J.LS OK. I never saw such a super high level proof. sorry

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for $n$ to ever be negative? Trying to figure out where I went wrong on some thing and want to rule that out.

$\Delta G$ is the maximum non expansion work and hence should be equal to external force under consideration times the distance for a reaction to be at equilibrium, hence we need to find that external force.

I know that from electrostatics that for a charge in a uniform electric field the force is $\bar F=q\bar E$. for $q=-1.6\times10^{-19}\ \mathrm C$. When we take our system to be $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of electrons, we have a total of $-1.6\times10^{-19}\ \mathrm C\times6.02\times10^{23}\approx -96500\ \mathrm C$ and we have that $1\ \mathrm F=96500\ \mathrm C$. So total force is:
$$\Delta G=W_\text{max,add}=\bar F_\text{ext}\cdot \bar d$$
$$\Delta G=\bar F_\text{ext}\cdot \bar d=q_\text{total}\cdot E\cdot 1\ \mathrm m=(-n) _\mathrm F\cdot E _\mathrm V=-nFE_\mathrm J$$

Now think, can the number of moles of electrons transferred be negative?

Answer (score -1):

$n$ cannot be negative.

$$\Delta G = -nFE$$

Transfer of $\ce{e-}$ cannot be negative.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality, probably because (1) you didn't make the effort to write full sentences, including punctuation or (2) you did not provide a clear answer. Please make changes or the answer risks being deleted.